# Elastic beanstalk instance not stopping instead terminating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to do key pair for elastic beanstalk instance in order to connect to instance but I need to stop then do key pair for that I am stopping the instance but its terminating and creating new instance. I can't do key pair on running instance. please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk creates the instance as part of an Auto Scaling group. When you 'stop' an ASG instance, ASG will kill it and recreate it. Basically, you can not 'stop' an ASG EC2 instance. Define your keypair in the Launch Configuration that you have defined. Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html) link which explains how can you define the keypair.

Comment: Resolved as per the above link. Thank you very much Krishna.